# Object reference not set to an instance of an object w/array

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding C# labels to a form at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736884/adding-c-sharp-labels-to-a-form-at-runtime)

I can't figure out what is making this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

code:

```
Line[] myLine = new Line[10];
int lineCount = 0;
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        myLine[lineCount].setPoint(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        ++pointCount;
        if (pointCount == 2)
        {
            pointCount = 0;
            ++lineCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here

```
myLine[lineCount].setPoint(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
```

You need to instantiate a new `Line` type element before using it.

do:

```
if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        myLine[lineCount] = new Line(); //instantiate the array element
        myLine[lineCount].setPoint(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        ++pointCount;
        if (pointCount == 2)
        {
            pointCount = 0;
            ++lineCount;
        }
}
```

It seems that Line is a class, (reference type) if you create an array of reference type then all the elements of the array gets the default value of `null`, and you can't call a instance method on `null` object.

[Example from MSDN - Single Dimension Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
SomeType[] array4 = new SomeType[10];
```

> The result of this statement depends on whether SomeType is a value
>   type or a reference type. If it is a value type, the statement results
>   in creating an array of 10 instances of the type SomeType. If SomeType
>   is a reference type, the statement creates an array of 10 elements,
>   each of which is initialized to a null reference.

Comment: Would be great if the downvoter can point to the mistake ..